# Battery heating issue

Tags: batteries, heat, thermistor

In my project, we are using Li-Polymer batteries. We have LCD and high-power components which will generate heat. We have an enclosure in which battery and LCD and other hardware will be fitted. We are using a thermistor on the battery to monitor the battery temperature, and our battery charger will terminate the charging if the temperature exceeds 45 degrees.

As there are high-power components which will generate heat, that heat is affecting the battery and the charger is disabling the charging. Can anyone suggest how we can protect the battery from the surrounding temperature?

Comment: Have a look at "heat pipes". THese are able to transfer thermal energy to another location with minimal energy loss - you need a means of cooling the "destination" butt his can allow you to eg insulate the heat source from the battery and then provide the battery with a heat sink at some other location in the equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can prevent battery from heat because heat you're talking about is ambient temperature but I can suggest these :

1)You can add passive cooler to battery (Like aluminum heatsink )

2)You can add simple insulation plate between battery and heat source but keep in mind battery produce heat too , so leave space for that or add extra cooler

3)I'm not a expert but I don't think 45 degrees much for lithium polymer battery so you can try to remove battery charge's temperature module

If you can add simple schematic , we can solve your problem more precisely

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1) I can't add a heat sink to the battery. because I am using an aluminium sheet metal as a back cover which is connected to the heat-generating component with TIM. So this aluminium will be at an higher temperature than 45.

Comment: 2)we have tried with insulation and it is charged for once. But at the time of discharging the battery will heat itself. And it cannot cool at that time, so it is not able to charge again.3) For lithium-poly battery, charging temperature is 0 to 45 degree. If try to charge the battery at a high temperature, there will be a chance for thermal runaway and battery life degradation. So I cannot remove this feature.

Comment: Please specify what schematics you are asking. Whether charging circuit you are asking?

Comment: You can use laptop CPU fan like system , if you have space : Add copper part to carry battery's heat and use aluminum heatsink (maybe with small fan) end of copper . As I said it all depend on your design . You can add insulation plate between battery and aluminum sheet , this way battery won't get any heat from your system